# Как вызвать анонимную функцию внутри onload в html теге?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div onload="function(e){ console.log(this) }">123</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вот так вызывать

```html
    <body onload="(()=>console.log(this))()">
```

Но это будет работать только для тега **body**

Для остальных тегов это не сработает

Comment: Насчет тегов, тут ссылка на атрибут https://msiter.ru/references/html-reference/events/onload и, с div, реально не будет работать: `Поддерживаемые HTML теги: <body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>`

Comment: ТС будет неприятно удивлён, когда будет обращаться к this))